# Arduino: Increasing and decreasing a variable with buttons

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

*Arduino Uno on Arduino IDE:*

Hi, I'm trying to increase the variable 'sspeed' by 0.01 when button1 is pressed, and decrease it by 0.01 when button2 is pressed.

Currently it won't work. I know its not the connections to the arduino, as I've tried serial printing 'b1' which returns 0 or 1 depending on weather its low or high.
So I'm guessing I've done something wrong in code.

My code is below:

```
float sspeed = 0.00;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

                            //(the buttons are 2 pin)
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP); //button1
  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP); //button2
}

void loop()
{
  int b1 = digitalRead(2);
  int b2 = digitalRead(3);

  Serial.println(sspeed);

  if (b1 = LOW) sspeed = sspeed + 0.01;
  if (b2 = LOW) sspeed = sspeed - 0.01;
}
```

Hope you can help, thanks.

Comment: You probably meant `if (b1 == LOW)` instead of an assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b1 = low` is an assignment. This will always set b1 to low and also evaluate to low which happens to be 0 which happens to be interpeted as false. `b1 == low` is probably the comparison you want. Once you fix this you will notice that this code will "autorepeat" to fast. The next thing that you will learn is button bounce. You may want to read what to do about this on the Arduino pages: http://playground.arduino.cc/code/bounce

Answer (score 0):

As said before, `b1 = LOW` is an assignment that always return true. To avoid this common mistake, that can even be a typo, you can use [Yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions), that is, put the value and then the variable.

```
if (LOW == b1)
```

Then, if you miss one `=` sign, you will have a compiling error and detect that mistake.

About bouncing, you can use a short delay to avoid it.

```
if (LOW == b1)
{
    delay(5);
    sspeed += 0.01;
}
```